# C# Import Excel Data to SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I am trying to use a method I pulled off of CodePlex, which exports data from Excel into a SQL table. I have made some minor code adjustments, but I still can't seem to get the data to import. Does anyone see anything glaringly wrong with my syntax? Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            importdatafromexcel("C:/Users/usname/Desktop/TestDirectories/FileSystemWatcher/Test_123.xlsx");
        }

public static void importdatafromexcel(string excelfilepath)
        {
            //declare variables - edit these based on your particular situation
            string ssqltable = "Name";
            // make sure your sheet name is correct, here sheet name is sheet1, so you can change your sheet name if have different

            string myexceldataquery = "select Name,EmployeeID from [sheet1$]";
            try
            {
                //create our connection strings
                string sexcelconnectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + excelfilepath + ";Extended Properties=" + "\"excel 8.0;hdr=yes;\"";

                //MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelfilepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'");

                string ssqlconnectionstring = "server=DESKTOP-6CIMC97;Initial Catalog=TestDB;integrated security=true;connection reset = false";

                //<add name="ProductContext" connectionString="Server=DESKTOP-6CIMC97; Initial Catalog=ProductApps; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

                //execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table
                string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
                sqlcmd.Connection.Open();
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();

                //series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our sql table
                OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
                OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
                oledbconn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                //while (dr.Read())
                //{
                  //  bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                //}

                oledbconn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the behavior you're actually getting. Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: I've tried but am new to programming and an not the best with the breakpoints. I've added one to the Excel connection and one to the actual method in Main, but I don't see any errors when I hover after it breaks. When I run the code the console app opens up and closes after about a second as if it has been successful, but when I check the table no data exists.

Comment: This looks like an opportunity to learn debugging :-) Try creating your own reader loop to see if the data can actually be read from the source table. Manually put random data in the table `Name` to see if it at least gets deleted. Just validate each step of the overall process.

Comment: I actually just added some code to my catch statement so I could debug a little better. This is my error, which seems like it has something to do with IIS... "the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
   bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
```

The `while (dr.Read())` block is useful if you are iterating over the results one-by-one.

But it's not you who is iterating over the results. You want the bulk copy operation to do the iterating.

Simply replace it with

```
bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I commented out my while statement and moved the bulkcopy commmand up, as shown in the code above now. It still doesn't seem to want to import. I'm worried its something within one of the connection strings. The db name is TestDB and the table is Name. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
private void SaveFileToDatabase(string filePath)
{
    String strConnection = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\Hemant\\documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\CRMdata\\CRMdata\\App_Data\\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    String excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", filePath);
    //Create Connection to Excel work book 
    using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
    {
        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel 
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID],[Name],[Designation] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection))
        {
            excelConnection.Open();
            using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                using(SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
                {
                    //Give your Destination table name 
                    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Excel_table";
                    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}


private string GetLocalFilePath(string saveDirectory, FileUpload fileUploadControl)
{


    string filePath = Path.Combine(saveDirectory, fileUploadControl.FileName);

    fileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath);

    return filePath;

}
```

For more info, see the links below.

https://www.codeproject.com/tips/636719/import-ms-excel-data-to-sql-server-table-using-csh

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/inserting-excel-file-records-into-sql-server-database-using/

As you can tell, there are MANY ways to do what you want to do.